# Пропуск итерации цикла при долгом отклике

Tags: c#

Задача следующая. Имеется файл с прокси, каждый прокси я проверяю выполняя вход на сайт, если прокси не рабочий или с плохим пингом, то цикл зависает или соответственно вход на сайт занимает большое кол-во секунд.

Мне нужно пропускать подобные итерации и переходить к следующему прокси в списке. То есть если итерация занимает скажем больше 15 секунд, то нужно ее пропустить.

Как правильно сделать это?

```
static void QueryToOrders()
    {
        const string sourceToSite = "https://whatleaks.com/ru/";
        foreach (var item in File.ReadLines("pathtolist"))
        {
            var _proxy = new WebProxy(item);//"85.187.10.196:8080"
            Requester req = new Requester(_proxy);
            var context = new Context(req);
            var document = context.Page.OpenAsync(sourceToSite);
            var IP = document.Result.Body.QuerySelectorAll("span")[3].TextContent; // если прокси не работает, то сайт не открыт и зависание на этой строке
        }          
    }
```

Comment: закинь это дело в таску и жди её 15 секунд например

Comment: за что минусуете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знаю, что вы используете для запроса, но я бы на вашем месте прпрбовал поискать где там есть установка таймаута соединения.

Если таймаут установить не удается, то вот я переделал ваш пример на асинхронный

```
static async Task QueryToOrders()
{
    const string sourceToSite = "https://whatleaks.com/ru/";
    foreach (var item in File.ReadLines("pathtolist"))
    {
        var _proxy = new WebProxy(item);//"85.187.10.196:8080"
        Requester req = new Requester(_proxy);
        var context = new Context(req);
        var document = context.Page.OpenAsync(sourceToSite);
        await Task.WhenAny(new[] {document, Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))});
        if (!document.IsCompleted)
        {
            // не успело отработать
        }
        else{
            var IP = document.Result.Body.QuerySelectorAll("span")[3].TextContent; 
        }

    }
}
```